# In the Telekinetic feat for Psionic Options Revisited, what if you already know the cantrip?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, feats, unearthed-arcana

The Telekinetic feat in the [UA 2020 Psionic Options Revisited](https://dnd.wizards.com/articles/unearthed-arcana/psionic-options-revisited) describes learning the Mage Hand cantrip, but without any components, and making it invisible. It says that if you already know the spell, that its range increases by 30ft. Is that on top of the no components and invisibility? Or does a spellcaster only gain the extra range?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### You get all the benefits.

The relevant section of the feat reads,

> You learn the mage hand cantrip. You can cast it without verbal or somatic components, and you can make the spectral hand invisible. If you already know this spell, its range increases by 30 feet when you cast it.

Nothing here suggests a character who already knows the cantrip doesn't get the first benefits; the extra range makes up for not gaining the benefit of learning a new cantrip.

I would expect wording with an "instead" in there if the ability was intended to be exclusive.